# How do I read a Latin language text, and be able to hold finger on words I don't know for instant definitions?

Tags: translation

I can read some Latin, but not enough to finish a book without a dictionary nearby. I'd like to read some old famous writings of the Romans. I'd be curious if anyone's figured out how to do this on any e-reader. I have Kindle, iPhone, and Android, but I would buy another e-reader if it had this feature.

It's important that a word I don't know can be instantly defined in place without having to open another app or lose my page. I know how to do this for the most common EFIGS languages (english, french, italian, german, spanish). But not for less common languages like Korean or Latin.

Comment: What is your kindle model?

Comment: Paperwhite, but i'll buy a new one if there's one that does this

Comment: Sorry, I have Kobo readers, but [this](https://www.amazonforum.com/s/question/0D54P00007KqUbG/how-do-i-install-a-latin-dictionary-on-my-kindle-paperwhite) looks promising.